# Does fopen(file, "w") write to a new block?

Tags: c

Does using fopen(fileName, "w") overwrite the blocks being used by a file, or does it set the blocks that were once being used as free and then start writing to new blocks?

Comment: Depends on the os and filesystem, and isn’t within the scope of C, so you need to specify more context.

Comment: That depends on the file system. Don't rely on it overwriting the actual blocks of the file. And even if it overwrites the actual blocks (or if you use some system-depend interface to do that) there's no telling what the actual storage will do, especially on flash memory, SSD, etc.

Comment: @Arkku I hadn't considered that. I am currently working on linux/ubuntu.

Comment: I'd generally assume the data *isn't* overwritten, except by coincidence. If you're concerned about leaving traces of the old file, I'd suggest removing the existing file via [the `shred` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) or the like. Even then though, not all file systems will support this behavior, and any file system on a flash drive will usually not overwrite in place on the physical storage.

Comment: Journalled file systems probably don’t overwrite the previous data. There’s no guarantee either way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler For COW filesystems  the guarantee is the old file blocks will **not** be overwritten...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard doesn’t specify how it’s implemented. So, it **might** overwrite the blocks, but there’s no guarantee. On a Unix/Unix-like environment, for example, it’s most likely a wrapper around `open()` with some internal `FILE *` manipulation that we need not worry about.